# Xcode Autolayout - Setting UIButton Width equal to view width

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I have a view with one UIButton with width equal to superview width. It renders correctly for iPhone 4s,5s but for 6+ it renders as shown below. I have tried adding constraints "trailing space to" "leading space to" to make it end to end but its not working and being new to layout I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Any chance you've also added a conflicting width constraint?

Comment: @bgilham No. I removed all constraints and added back those two constraints. Still its same.

Comment: DId you find your solutions

Answer (score 1):

There are for things you have to work out with when you use autolayout...i.e.

- x position of object
- Y position of object
- Height of Object
- Width of object

here is the image for your button constraints and how it works...

[image]

At the first stage where i pinned `leading space`,`trailing space` and `height` i.e gives button height, width and x position....

But still i need Y position... so i gave Horizontal and vertical center constraints....

> instead of this you can use top space constrain or only use vertical constraint instead of both Horizontal and vertical center constraints for Y position....

and the output screen is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your "Add new constraints" popup do following:

1. Disable "Constrain to margins" checkbox
2. Add left and right constraints, set constants to 0.
3. Add height constraint.
4. Click "Add 3 constraints"
   That's it!
   [image]